# Can we use adjective after noun?

Tags: adjective-phrases, postpositive-adjectives

People **angry with the high prices** were protesting.

Can we use adjective after noun without verb to be like the example above?

Can you tell me what grammar rule is it?

Comment: The first question is easy; yes, you can surely use that construct. The key is the prepositional phrase; if you removed the "with the high prices" part, you'd want to change the wording to: _Angry people were protesting_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As J.R. says, that construction is grammatical, and indeed required.

A bare adjective, or one modified by one or more preceding adverbs, goes in front of the noun. (I'm adding a determiner, *many*, to your sentence, to make the structure a little less ambiguous.)

> Many angry people were protesting.
> Many passionately and vociferously angry people were protesting.

But an adjective which has a complement cannot be placed in front of the noun; it must be treated as a reduced relative clause<sup>†</sup> and placed **after** the noun.

> <sup>∗</sup> Many angry with the high prices people were protesting.
>    Many people angry with the high prices were protesting.

If the adjective is modified it will carry its modifiers with it.

> Many people passionately and vociferously angry with the high prices were protesting.

The same thing is true of any ‘heavy’ modifier with an embedded complement, such as a participle phrase or an adjectival preposition phrase:

> <sup>∗</sup> Many suffering from hunger people were protesting.
>    Many people suffering from hunger were protesting.
>
> <sup>∗</sup> Many from the surrounding villages people were protesting.
>    Many people from the surrounding villages were protesting.

---

As Laure says, the clause may be bracketed with commas. This changes the meaning, however: the clause is now ‘non-restrictive’ rather ‘restrictive’: being angry with high prices no longer defines the people who were protesting, it is an additional observation about them. A non-restrictive clause can be placed in other places:

> Passionately and vociferously angry with the high prices, many people were protesting.
> Many people were protesting, passionately and vociferously angry with the high prices.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  before an utterance marks it as ungrammatical.

<sup>†</sup> A reduced relative clause is one from which the relative pronoun and any immediately following copula have been deleted as unnecessary: *<strike>who were</strike> angry with the high prices*.