# Is 'nomenclature' grammatically correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'nomenclature' grammatically correct in this context?

> Pseudo-code contained in the article will be presented in a
>   programming language [name of programming language], which combines
>   informatics and mathematical nomenclature.

Comment: Grammatically, there should be a noun there, and nomenclature is a noun. So, yes, grammatically it is correct. I would worry more about whether the word fits _semantically_. :)

Comment: “Nomenclature” seems fine here, although the meaning is not very clear to me. “Contained in the article” sticks out, however. Do you mean that **pseudo-codes in the article will be presented in** a specific programming language? In that case, you will want to order it as I have. “Contained in the article” is too big and strange to work as an adjectival phrase. Also, you will want to use the definite article when referring to **“the** programming language [name]” unless you write it as “a programming language **called** [name]” or something like that.

Comment: Grammatically, the problems are: (1) *pseudo-code* shouldn't be pluralised, and (2) it should come ***before*** the [optional] clause *contained in the article*.

Comment: Do you mean that pseudo-codes in the article will be presented in a specific programming language? Yes.

Comment: I corrected sentence structure and now I'm wondering if it is grammatically correct? Contained pseudo-codes in the dissertation will be presented in the programming language [name of programming language], which combines informatics and mathematical nomenclature.

Comment: You’d rather used “which combines nomenclature of both informatics and mathematics.”

Comment: I think what you mean in your opening phrase is "Pseudocode contained in the article". As FumbleFingers suggests, in English an adjective or participle which is followed by a complement must be placed **after** the noun it modifies; see [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13322/32). In addition, 'pseudo-code' in English is not pluralized to signify 'multiple passages in pseudo-code'; instead, the bare indeterminate noun is used. I have taken the liberty of making these changes to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the use of “nomenclature”, but I'd make things more symmetric by either writing “informatical and mathematical nomenclature” or “nomenclature from (both) computer sciences and mathematics”. Unless you explicitely want to stress that “mathematical nomenclature” is one item and “informatics” is the other, which would be gramatically correct but seems a bit odd semantically, since you'd be comparing a field of science with – well – nomenclature.